# Please help guide if my understanding is correct

Tags: circuit-analysis, electrical

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Please help check if my understanding is correct for the above circuits. As per my understanding the Voc=4v, since we have opened the circuit and there is no current flow. If that was not the case we would have applied the voltage divider to find the voltage in that branch.Kindly let me know if further explanation is required from my side.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your understanding is correct indeed.

Comment: yep...you are right

Answer (score 0):

In both circuits, you have open loops so there is no current flowing, no current no power consumption, does not matter how many Resistor are there, you only get the Voltage-source voltage at the end of the Network.

Comment: "does not matter how many Resistor are there". What if the number of Resistors is infinite, or one of the finite numbers of resistors is an infinite one?